# angular remove element from dom if src does not exist

Tags: angularjs

I have an img element with a ng-src attribute that will show / hide if the models image value exists, something like the following:

```
<img ng-show="model.image" ng-src="img/{{model.image}}"/>
```

which works fine. But it obviously still makes a GET request to the server for "...img/" when no image value exists. How can I stop it from making this request? I guess I need to conditionally remove the element from the DOM and should be placing my DOM manipulation in a directive but I'm not sure exactly how to approach this. Cheers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Angular 1.1.5 introduced the [ng-if](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.directive:ngIf) directive to conditionally remove the element from the DOM. You need to use it instead of ng-show.

If you are using an older version of Angular, consider using angular-ui's [ui-if](https://github.com/angular-ui/angular-ui/blob/master/modules/directives/if/if.js) directive.